# When Linux boots, do interrupts get disabled on all processors or just the processor it is running on?

Tags: linux, interrupt, boot

I'm trying to find where in the Linux bootup process it disables the interrupts. I have 2 questions:

1) When Linux disables interrupts during bootup, does it disable interrupts on all processors or just the processor it is running on?

2) Where in code does this happen?

I see `local_irq_disable()` in `kernel/main.c` and throughout the assembly code for arm64 in the `arch/` directory, which suggests that only irqs for the current processor it is running on are disabled.

Is this an accurate conclusion to draw?